# AngularJs: Load disqus comments in ng-view

Tags: angularjs, disqus, ng-view

I have included disqus script into my html file which is loaded in `ng-view` but it shows nothing. However when I move the script out of the `ng-view` it work fine.
Is there a way to load disqus comments inside `ng-view`?

Here is the html file:

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>

var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = 'http://example-com';  // Replace PAGE_URL with your   page's canonical URL variable
this.page.identifier = 'http://example-com'; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER  with your page's unique identifier variable
};

(function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
s.src = '//example-com.disqus.com/embed.js';
s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
(d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?    ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Have you tried [angular-disqus](https://github.com/kirstein/angular-disqus/) or a similar ng-directive?

Comment: I just try it but it doesn't work. Same problem.

Comment: Attach your code samples and architecture please

Comment: are you testing on localhost? disqus wants the url, that is registered.

Comment: Yes I work on localhost but I can see the disqus comment box when I move it out of the ng-view. So the issue is about how to get it inside ng-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find a [Disqus Directive](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/disqus) that save me

Thank you all